# Can smbclient put quietly?

Tags: smbclient

I invoke `smbclient` from cron to upload backups to an entertainment set-top box, which only speaks SMB. The device has a large disk and is far away from the computers making it a good place to store backups.

It goes something like:

```bsh
backup-outputing-commang | smbclient //box/share -c "put - backups/filename"
```

Things work fine, but `put` is noisy -- at the end of the upload it always outputs something like:

```
putting file - as \backups\filename (3604.2 kb/s) (average 3604.2 kb/s)
```

Which output causes `cron` to send me a useless e-mail... I don't want to redirect the output to `/dev/null` for fear of missing some real problem (and I don't trust those to always be sent to `stderr`).

Is there some kind of quiet mode in put? The [manual page](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smbclient.1.html) only mentions "quiet" for the `tar` command -- how do I shut up `put`?

Comment: Can you make this a proper _answer_ so I can accept it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't obvious in the man page, but the default debug level is 1, and by setting it to 0 you can get less output, i.e. `-d 0`

> At level 0, only critical errors and serious warnings will be logged.

Answer (score 0):

The message is written to stdout, so you could filter it out:

```
backup-outputing-commang | smbclient //box/share -c "put - backups/filename" | grep -v "putting file"
```

Comment: Do you trust `smbclient` to never output anything unusual or abnormal to `stdout`, though?

Comment: Yes, that's right. You'd have to check the logs to find the error. I updated the question, though probably you want to use @meuh's comment.